# Packing images together with the main file with pyinstaller --onefile problem

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, ttk

I'm building my first program with pyinstaller and I need to add the assets folder to the build, and in the script I use

```py
tk.PhotoImage(file='./image.png')
```

This works petty good without `--onefile`

```py
pyinstaller.exe --add-data 'assets;assets' --collect-data sv_ttk .\main.py
```

But when I use `--onefile` I have and `FileNotFound` error..
I think the problem is in using './' in my images, any solution?

[image: No Such File or Dir]

Comment: If those images are inside `assets` folder, then `tk.PhotoImage(file='./image.png')` should raise file not found exception.

Comment: ya exact what happens, to any solutions? @acw1668

Comment: It should be `tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/image.png")` instead if the image is inside `assets` folder.  Also the command line of running `PyInstaller` should be `pyinstaller --add-data "assets;assets" main.py` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 ty for that, it works to add assets to build folder! Updated question, to --onefile problem

Comment: Take a look on ["Runtime Information"](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with @acw1668 link with

```py
import sys
from os import path

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)))
    return path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

and all my PhotoImages is now

```py
PhotoImage(file=resource_path('assets/icon.png'))
```

Now I can build --onefile without problems

*expect to help future users :)